# How to see post of all Team Members

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a two table named Team and team_user. Here is the Schema of the both table

```
            Team Table
---------------------------------
| id | team_name | user_id      |
---------------------------------
|  1 | Developer |     5        |
|  2 | Designer  |     6        |
|  3 | Test      |     7        |
|  4 | Test 2    |     8        |
---------------------------------

               Team_User Table
-------------------------------------------------
| id | team_id   |   tl_id      |   user_id     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    1      |     5        |   25          |
|  2 |    2      |     6        |   35          |
|  3 |    2      |     7        |   12          |
|  4 |    3      |     8        |   13          |
-------------------------------------------------
```

`tl_id (Team Leader User ID)
user_id (User ID of user who is under Team leader)`

A Team leader can have multiple user under him. I want to show All the post of his team member in Team Leader view.

So for e.g if Team Leader named abc has a member named def under him and Another person named ghi is under def. So i want to show all post of def and ghi under abc Leaders view.

Till now i have done this -

```
   $user = auth()->user();
    $teams =  DB::table('team_user')->where('tl_id', $user->id)->get();
    $tl = array();
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
        $tl[] = $team->user_id;
    }
    $tl[] = auth()->user()->id; 

    $posts = DB::table('post')->where('status',1)->Where(function ($query) use($tl) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($tl); $i++){
                $query->orwhere('user_id', '=', $tl[$i]);
            }
        })->get();
```

From above code i can only get the post list of def under abc. How can i get the post ghi too and so on under him?

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Comment: Do you mean you need alls under a Team leaders with including nested team members(like one team member may be leading another set of members and so on..) ?

Comment: Yes @MihirBhende. Other person can be a leader of another person

Comment: What is `tl_id`? Is it team leader ID?

Comment: Can you show some expected output and what are the primary keys and foreign keys here?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution by this code logic

```
$user = auth()->user();
        $teams =  DB::table('team_user')->where('tl_id', $user->id)->get();
        $tl = array();
        foreach ($teams as $team) {
            $tl[] = (int)$team->user_id;
            $searches = DB::table('team_user')->where('tl_id',$team->user_id)->get();
            foreach($searches as $search){
                $tl[] = (int)$search->user_id;
                $searched = DB::table('team_user')->where('tl_id',$search->user_id)->get();
                foreach($searched as $searchd){
                    $tl[] = (int)$searchd->user_id;
                }

            }
        }
```